# How do I find where a symbol is defined among static libraries

Tags: c++, linker, libraries, undefined-symbol

Suppose you work with a codebase comprising several tools and libraries and you want to port (or resurrect) some component within such codebase but any clue about where symbols lie within the various libs is either lost or will take ages to find out by looking at the code itself (yes improved documentation can avoid such issues but is quite demanding). What is the fastest way to discover in which library you can find symbols used in the code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `nm`, it is possible to list the symbols defined in a binary, and the `--defined-only` switch ignores undefined references.

### Option 1: `find`

In a single command:

```sh
find $path -name \*.a -exec bash -c "nm --defined-only {} 2>/dev/null | grep $symbol && echo {}" \;
```

where `$path` is the root of the file tree containing the binaries, and `$symbol` is the name of the symbol you are looking for.

### Option 2: `find` + GNU `parallel`

Running `nm` on all files can take time, so it could be helpful to process the results of `find` in parallel (using GNU `parallel`):

```sh
find $path -name \*.a | parallel "nm --defined-only {} 2>/dev/null | grep $symbol && echo {}"
```

### Option 3: `fd`

And at last, my favourite. Using the [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) tool, that has a simpler syntax than `find`, is generally faster, and processes the results in parallel by default:

```sh
fd '.*\.a$' -x bash -c "nm --defined-only {} 2>/dev/null | grep $symbol && echo {}"
```

### Simple benchmark

Searching for the `gz_write` symbol in `/usr/lib` on my laptop:

- `find` takes around 23 seconds
- `find | parallel` takes around 10 seconds
- `fd` takes around 8 seconds

Answer (score 35):

Assuming a linux box, the **nm** tool, listing names in library files, comes to the rescue.

It can be used to do an extensive search as follows: one can first find all the libraries available (assuming the project have been successfully compiled without the component you are adding) with a find, then such find can be enclosed in a loop where you call nm on all discovered libraries; the output you then grep for discarding "U" references (undefined symbols, aka where else the symbol is being used). On a single bash line that gives:

```
for lib in $(find base_path -name \*.a) ; do echo $lib ; nm $lib | grep my_symbol | grep -v " U "   ; done
```

where:

- base_path is the root of your codebase
- my_symbol is the symbol you are looking for

The echo generates a list of all libraries found, which is not so clean since it outputs names of libs not holding the symbol, but it was the fastest way I found to have a direct reference to the library so when you see a:

```
base_path/component/libA.a
0000000000000080 D my_symbol
```

You have found your usual suspect.

Comment: the -A option to nm will print the filename.  Removing the need to echo $lib in your example.

Answer (score 4):

Using nm's `--defined-only` switch is helpful here since it will remove the undefined references. Below is a csh script that may be useful to others.

```
#!/bin/csh
#
#recurse from current dir and output name of any .a files
#that contain the desired symbol.
echo "Search for: $1"
foreach i (`find . -name '*.a'`)
    nm --defined-only $i | grep $1
    if ($status == 0) then
        echo $i
    endif
end
```